# Difference between char str[1] and char *str in this context?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

While studying some code I encountered the following struct:

```
/* PACKET format:
 * 
 *     clientRandom  - 20 byte buffer
 *     yLen          - 4 bytes (LoHi integer)
 *     yData         - yLen byte buffer
 *
 *   Total length = 24 + yLen bytes
*/
typedef struct packetFormat
{
    char clientRandom[20];
    uint32 yLen;
    char yData[1];
}packetFormat;
```

Why the third field not declared as `char *yData` since its a char buffer of variable length?

Comment: How is use this field in code?

Comment: No code available, its in a header file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a thing called [struct hack](http://c-faq.com/struct/structhack.html).

Comment: Is there any other possibility? If not, I can be sure, it is implemented this way only.

Comment: Anyways, Thanks, for the answer. It seems to be most likely way to use it.

Comment: I'm not hundred per cent sure, if there are other possibilities. But I haven't seen any other ones so far.